# Topic Visual Basic Statement Means

Tags: vba

Please explain what does this statements means taken from code
I'm new to VB, it will be much appreciated. Thanks.

```
'Statement

While Not MyRec.EOF  ' Loop trough the table
    MyList = MyList & ";" & MyRec![email]
    MyRec.MoveNext
Wend

MyList = Mid(MyList, 2)



'Below CODE

function GetMailList()
    Dim MyDB As DAO.Database, MyRec As DAO.Recordset, MyList As String
    Set MyDB = CurrentDb
    Set MyRec = MyDB.OpenRecordset("Select email From TableName")

    While Not MyRec.EOF  ' Loop trough the table
        MyList = MyList & ";" & MyRec![email]
        MyRec.MoveNext
    Wend

    MyList = Mid(MyList, 2)

    ' use you code here with the mail list ceated

    MyRec.Close
    MyDB.Close
End Function
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. create a connection to database and fetch data**

```
Dim MyDB As DAO.Database, MyRec As DAO.Recordset, MyList As String
Set MyDB = CurrentDb
Set MyRec = MyDB.OpenRecordset("Select email From TableName")
```

**2. while there are unread records in myRec, loop through the records. here EOF means `End-Of-File`**

```
While Not MyRec.EOF  ' Loop trough the table

    MyList = MyList & ";" & MyRec![email]
    'this will append the eMail field to the string

    MyRec.MoveNext
Wend
```

**3. now that all the e-mails heve ben concatinated to the string (we have a semi-colon seperated values of e mails), close the connection and all**

```
MyRec.Close
MyDB.Close
```

Comment: Aha! got it

This statement assigns MyList equals to MyRec[Email] ?
MyList = MyList & ";" & MyRec![email]

How come it gives me an error when i removed the While Loop and replaced it with
    MyList = MyRec[email]

it gives me an error?

and what function did this line use? I can't get what Mid and 2 means :S
MyList = Mid(MyList, 2)

Big Thanks!

Comment: search for vb [string concatenation](https://www.google.com/search?q=vb+string+concatenation), [ado](https://www.google.com/search?q=ado+tutorial) and [mid function](https://www.google.com/search?q=vb+mid+function)

Comment: mid() function returns string, but i still don't get where in the code sets MyList= MyRec
'My Rec holds the Query, but how do i place the value of a query in a string where i can compare it to another string?

Comment: > i still don't get where in the code sets MyList= MyRec

    MyList = MyList & ";" & MyRec![email]

> My Rec holds the Query

No, it doesnt. it holds one of the rows returned after executing the query

> how do i place the value of a query in a string

see @idle_mind's answer. you have that string in MyList variable.
**i would suggest you write some basic programs of string-operation, database calls using ado etc.** [this](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/vbscript_examples.asp) would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

This concatenates all the values from the email column in the TableName table into one long string separated by semi-colons.

So at the end of the loop you'd have something like:

```
;address1@something.com;address2@something.com;address3@something.com
```

Note that the semi-colon is at the front, not the back, because of the way the concatenation was written.  The last line gets rid of the first semi-colon by replacing the string with itself starting at the second character.

Comment: `MyList = Mid(MyList, 2)` is there to remove the extra semi-colon at the front.

Comment: Isn't that what I said with: "The last line gets rid of the first semi-colon by replacing the string with itself starting at the second character."

Comment: *Its the last line in the first snippet block at least.  =)

Comment: got it! u were right.

Comment: Aha! got it

This statement assigns MyList equals to MyRec[Email] ?
MyList = MyList & ";" & MyRec![email]

How come it gives me an error when i removed the While Loop and replaced it with
    MyList = MyRec[email]

it gives me an error?

Big Thanks!